# Javascript API to hide navigation breadcrumb and header

Tags: tableau-api

Using Tableau Server 9.2. I am playing with the Javascript API to embed vizs in web pages. It works nicely except I want to hide the top part of the viz page, everything including and above the navigation breadcrumb part. The part circle in red is what I want to remove from the embedded viz. What options can be used to hide this part of the embedded viz?

[image]

Here is my html and js code to embed the viz.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://online.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableauViz"></div>

<script>
  var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
  var url = "https://tableau.byu.edu/#/site/DCE/views/Tableauworkbooksanddatasources/UnpublishedWorkbooks?:embed=y";
  var options = {
     hideTabs: true,
     width: "800px",
     height: "700px",
     hideToolbar: true,
     onFirstInteractive: function() {
       // The viz is now ready and can be safely used.
     }
  };
  var viz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
</script>
```

Comment: In your visualisation there will be a `share` button. Use the link provided in that

Answer (score 2):

For `var url`

Replace the current link with the link that is inside under `share` button .

Do not use the link under `Embed` , rather use the one below `Email`.

`share` button can be found when you open your viz. inside tableau .

Let me know if this works .

Comment: That worked. Turns out that the /#/site# I was using needed to be replaced by /t/.